# How to display all childrens from a Firebase node in a RecyclerView in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple Firebase database which look like this:

[image]

I want to display all this names into a `RecyclerView`. This is my code from `onCreate` method:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Names");
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
adapter = new RoomFirebaseAdapter(databaseReference, this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have also created a `CustomFirebaseAdapter` which `extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomFirebaseAdapter.ViewHolder>`. Here is my `onBindViewHolder` method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RoomFirebaseAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                name = ds.getKey();
                holder.textView.setText(name);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

The problem is, that in my `RecyclerView` is displyed only the last item. How can i display all the items in the `RecyclerView`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extract the `addValueEventListener` from the `onBindViewHolder` and in this method only set the holder. Eventually you can also use a `ChildEventListener` e.g.:

```
private ArrayList<String> names;

public CustomFirebaseAdapter() {
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Names");
    updateNames();
}

private void updateNames() {
    ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
            final String name = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            names.add(name);
            notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);
        }
        ...
    };
    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final TodoViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final String name = names.get(position);
    if (name == null) { return; }

    holder.textView.setText(name);
}
```

I have had the same problem and solved it this way: [example](https://github.com/Blackjack92/TodoManager/blob/master/TodoManagerAndroid/app/src/main/java/blackjack92/todomanager/adapter/TodoAdapter.java)

After some debugging we found out, that the problem was that the item layout took the whole space from the parent `match_parent` after changing to `wrap_content` everything worked.

Comment: Thank you, but when i try to implement `final String name = getItem(position);` i got this error: `Cannot resolve method getItem(int)`. What can i do?

Comment: it does nothing more than returning: `names.get(position)` if `names` is your array - i updated my answer

Comment: It is not working. Now i got a `FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`. This is my [CustomFirebaseAdapter](http://alexmamo.ro/RoomFirebaseAdapter.java). In stead of names, i have now rooms. Do you have any idea why is not getting me all the data?

Comment: On my domain. It's a simple java file.

Comment: i mean so that i can download it and test it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133354/discussion-between-kevin-wallis-and-alex-m).

Comment: Perfect answer! You helped me so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write a separated converter, which actually converts the data in the method of onDataChange(). Than you pass it to your presenter which hold a reference on the RecycleView

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    assets = AssetConverter.convert(dataSnapshot);
    gridPresenter.populate(assets);
}
```

where the gridPresenter is your class to hold reference on the RecycleView and it's adapter.

```
public void populate(List<Asset> assets) {
    adapter.setData(assets);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```